# How to add the results from the database using php

Tags: php, mysql, operators

Hi guys i am a newbie in php. I have a code in php I want to add data in mysql like this

Table **sample**

```
id   value1 value2  P_id
1    100     200     10
2    200     50      10
```

Here is my code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from sample P_id = '10'");
while($row = mysql_num_rows($query)){
    // Here is the condition I don't now what will be the code if I want to add
}
```

like this I want a result for value1 will be 300 and value2 250 when I display could you please help me with this thanks a lot

Comment: You're not very clear in what you want to achieve, but first you have an error in the select statement. You're missing the `where`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `where` in your select:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from sample WHERE P_id = '10'");
```

Comment: ok I have tested it.. i want to add the result of the rows how can i do this?

Comment: Easy, view @Shankar Damodaran answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right query you need run up against..

```
   mysql_query("SELECT SUM(value1) as Value1, SUM(value2) as Value2 FROM sample WHERE P_id = '10'");
   while($row = mysql_num_rows($query)){
    echo "Value 1:$row['Value1'];  Value 2:$row['Value2']";
   }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Value1 Value2
300    250
```

Comment: That's one of my option sir. but do we have any solution here? or no more?

Comment: combine @houssni and this answer, I think you will have what you want

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid SQL statement:

```
SELECT * from sample P_id = '10'
```